# How to write a class method to simulate object being eliminated by another in Python?

Tags: python, class

It's my first time using python class, so please forgive me if the code seems too clumsy to you guys.
I want to use python class to create a class containing Game of Throne characters in which I write a "kill" function to enable one character to slay another thus adding 1 person to his killing record (integer), and the killed  character will be deleted from memory and no longer reachable. Here is my code:

```
import gc
class Character():
  population = 0

  def __init__(self, name, house, castle):
      self.name = name
      self.house = house
      self.castle = castle
      self.kill=0
      print('{0} comes to the world of ice and fire!!!'.format(self.name))
      Character.population += 1

  def __str__(self):
      return 'I am {0} of house {1}, I live in {2}.'.format(self.name,
      self.house, self.castle)

  def __del__(self):  
      print ('{0} of house {1} has been slain.'.format(self.name, self.house))
      Character.population -= 1


  # My kill function:

  def kill(slayer, slain):
     print('{0} of house {1} has slain {2} of house {3}!'.format(slayer.name, slayer.house, slain.name, slain.house))
     slayer.kill +=1

     while len(gc.get_referrers(slain))!=0:
         del slain

c1=Character('Jofferry','Baratheon',"King's landing")
c2=Character('Eddard','stark','Winterfell' )

print('c1 has',len(gc.get_referrers(c1)),'reference(s)')
print('c2 has',len(gc.get_referrers(c2)),'reference(s)')

Character.kill(c1,c2)
```

At first I wrote directly
    del slain
at the end of my kill function, when I ran the code, it gave me this:

> Jofferry comes to the world of ice and fire!!!
>   Eddard comes to the world of ice and fire!!!
>   c1 has 1 reference(s)
>   c2 has 1 reference(s)
>   Jofferry of house Baratheon has slain Eddard of house stark!
>   c1 has 1 reference(s)
>   c2 has 1 reference(s)

which means the del function didn't work at all. So I tried the gc.get_referrers function and I wrote:

```
while len(gc.get_referrers(slain))!=0:
     del slain
```

but it gave me:

> Jofferry comes to the world of ice and fire!!!
>   Eddard comes to the world of ice and fire!!!
>   c1 has 1 reference(s)
>   c2 has 1 reference(s)
>   Jofferry of house Baratheon has slain Eddard of house stark!
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/xiasu/Meca3/Python/Stackoverflow.py", line 37, in 
>          Character.kill(c1,c2)
>   File "/home/xiasu/Meca3/Python/Stackoverflow.py", line 27, in kill
>          while len(gc.get_referrers(slain))!=0:

```
   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slain' referenced before assignment
```

and I don't understand what it means. Help me please, thanks in advance!!
(BTW: In python is it possible to define a instance variable(e.g: spouse in my case) which is also an object in the same class (Character)? If it is, how can I initialise it in '**init**'?)

Comment: The `UnboundLocalError` means the first time through the `while` loop, it removes the reference to `slain`. `slain` no longer points to an object (but that doesn't mean the object doesn't exist -- it's simply been dereferenced!) The `while` loop tries to run again but fails when it tries to look up `slain`, since you just dereferenced that variable!

Comment: Note also that your `def kill` will replace your `self.kill=0`.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but why it doesn't trigger the __del__ function if it is dereferenced?

Comment: It doesn't trigger the `del` function. It errors out on `while len(gc.ge_referrers(slain)) != 0` when it looks for `slain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sane way to do this is to wrap it all in a class.

```
class GameOfThrones(object):

    def __init__(self, kingdom):
        self.kingdom = kingdom
        self.population = {}

    def create_character(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = Character(*args, **kwargs)
        self.population[c.name] = c

    def kill_character(self, killer, victim):
        self.population[killer].kill(self.population[victim])
        del self.population[victim]

class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, name, house, castle):
        self.name = name
        self.house = house
        self.castle = castle
        self.victims = []
        self.alive = True

    @property
    def kills(self):
        return len(self.victims)

    def kill(self, other):
        other.dies()
        self.victims.append(other)
        print("{} killed {}".format(self.name, other.name))

    def dies(self):
        self.alive = False

game = GameOfThrones()

game.create_character("Joffrey", "Baratheon", "King's Landing")
game.create_character("Eddard", "Stark", "Winterfell")

game.kill_character("Eddard", "Joffrey")
```

That said, this is BARELY "sane." There's really no great reason to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam! I'll give you feedback as soon as I try your code, but now I really need to get some sleep

Comment: I've tested your code, except that I think the _dies_ function isn't supposed to have an _other_ variable, all works fine.  Basically what you're saying is instead of trying to delete a character in the memory (which may prove difficult) we can delete it in a predefined dictionary, right?

Comment: Good catch. I'd originally put the `victims.append` logic in `dies`.

Comment: I think it's a good solution, but you said there is no great reason to do this, what do you mean by that? What do Python coders do to get rid off no longer wanted objects?

Comment: @xiasuYang Pythonistas let the garbage collector handle memory allocation. That's its job :-)

Comment: Yeah, I read a little about that somewhere, but it seems pointless unless you have serious computational works to do. Anyway, I will do my research on that, thanks!

Comment: Just for a bit more detail, do we actuelly need __**kwargs__ and __@property__ in this case? Cos I don't really have a dictionary in __Character__, and I don't know what @property is for.

Comment: `property` attributes are (essentially) functions that act like variables. `some_char.kills` runs that function and returns the result. `kwargs` maintains flexibility if you were ever to change this class to have specific keyword args, or inherit it from a different class that uses them.

Comment: But if I don't use __@property__ , won't the __kills__  function work just fine?

Comment: Sure get it will be more like `get_kills` and you'll have to call it each time with `c.get_kills()`. To me, that's a property because it's an attribute about the character, not an action the character should take, that needs to be calculated at call time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're trying to do.  You can't "delete an object from memory".  `del` deletes a *reference* to the object (for instance, a variable called `slain`).  If other objects still hold a reference to the "slain" character, that's their business.  You can't destroy their references.

For your example, it's not clear why you would need to do that anyway.  You could just set a flag on the object like `slain.dead = True` to mark the character as dead.

Comment: Thank you! I admit slain.dead is also a good idea to do this. But isn't it true that if I enter directly del(slain) in the shell, all its references will be destroyed?

Comment: @XiasuYang: No.  Only the variable called `slain` will be removed, and any other references to that object will still exist.